# Performing set-difference with Multiple Set Arguments

Tags: common-lisp, set-difference

The function `set-difference` is restricted to finding the difference between two sets. Can this be efficiently extended to allow more set arguments--eg, `(my-set-difference A B C)`--in the same way the function `-` works--eg, `(- 9 3 1) => 5`? Using `(reduce #'set-difference ...)` is not very efficient, as it first requires appending all of the set arguments into a sequence.

Comment: Why is `(list set1 set2 set3 ...)` too inefficient?

Comment: why "appending"?? no, just putting them into a list, `(reduce #'set-difference (list A B C))`, which has minuscule performance const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think concatenating all the lists except the first one is probably the best solution.

Each invocation of `set-difference` will be `O(n)` (where `n` is the maximum size of the two lists), so reducing will be `O(n*m)` (where `m` is the number of lists). But if you do

```
(set-difference A (append B C D E F ...))
```

Appending all the lists is `O(total length of B...)`, and the complexity of `set-difference` will be similar.

Comment: on the other hand, append may create a large list for nothing whereas reduce produces only lists that are at most the size of the max. size of all lists, and the accumulated result only shrinks,

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how accurate the following quick test is, but it says Barmar's append method is about 14 times faster than the reduce method, but conses twice as much.

```
(defparameter A 
  (mapcar (lambda (elt)
            (declare (ignore elt))
            (random 100))
          (make-list 100)))

(defparameter B 
  (mapcar (lambda (elt)
            (declare (ignore elt))
            (random 100))
          (make-list 100)))


(defparameter C 
  (mapcar (lambda (elt)
            (declare (ignore elt))
            (random 100))
          (make-list 100)))

* (time (dotimes (i 100000) (reduce #'set-difference (list A B C))))
Evaluation took:
  0.877 seconds of real time
  0.875000 seconds of total run time (0.875000 user, 0.000000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.016 seconds GC time, and 0.859 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.77% CPU
  3,155,360,287 processor cycles
  78,380,176 bytes consed

NIL
* (time (dotimes (i 100000) (set-difference A (append B C))))
Evaluation took:
  0.064 seconds of real time
  0.062500 seconds of total run time (0.062500 user, 0.000000 system)
  96.88% CPU
  229,293,666 processor cycles
  159,971,568 bytes consed

NIL
```

But I've heard the SBCL time report is not very accurate (and this test may be faulty!).

Comment: Weird that it's so much slower. Funnily enough, if you write the expression that the `reduce` is supposed to be equivalent to, `(set-difference (set-difference A B) C)`, it becomes even faster than the `append` approach.

Comment: @Rord Amazing speed, and no consing.